# Inline Python Markdown is not computed when exporting from notebook to html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm using the Python Markdown extension in my Jupyter notebooks, that so far works great in a live notebook:

[image: working extension in live ipynb]

However when I'm trying to export it as html (I'm using the GUI for this: `File > Download as > HTML (.html)`), the inline code is no longer computed:

[image: non working html]

The [doc](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html#exporting) says to add these lines to the `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` configuration file:

```
c = get_config()
c.Exporter.preprocessors = ['pre_pymarkdown.PyMarkdownPreprocessor']
```

However that file did not exist in my `%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter` folder, only the JSON `jupyter_nbconvert_config.json`. I generated it with `jupyter nbconvert --generate-config` in my conda prompt and added the lines.

I have the `pre_pymarkdown.py` script in my *"strmlt"* env folder: `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\strmlt\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\nbconvert_support\pre_pymarkdown.py"`

But this all still doesn't solve my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cool, didn't know Jupyter markdown supports double curly brackets +1